# Sorting a group in datatable based on result in rows

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to do a group sorting on Datatables. As of now I am having data like:

```
+-------+-----+--------+
| rowno | mno | result |
+-------+-----+--------+
|     1 |  80 |     20 |
|     1 |  81 |     10 |
|     1 |  82 |     30 |
|     2 |  80 |     40 |
|     2 |  81 |     50 |
|     2 |  82 |     60 |
|     3 |  80 |     70 |
|     3 |  81 |     60 |
|     3 |  82 |     50 |
+-------+-----+--------+
```

As per the requirement , i will be selecting a particular mno, lets say 81 and then depending on the result for 81 i.e. 10, 50 and 60, I would like to sort entire group in descending order. Which means the result would be something like:

```
+-------+-----+--------+
| rowno | mno | result |
+-------+-----+--------+
|     3 |  80 |     70 |
|     3 |  81 |     60 |
|     3 |  82 |     50 |
|     2 |  80 |     40 |
|     2 |  81 |     50 |
|     2 |  82 |     60 |
|     1 |  80 |     20 |
|     1 |  81 |     10 |
|     1 |  82 |     30 |
+-------+-----+--------+
```

I am having the entire set as Datatable and am thinking of applying Linq to solve this one. Or if a SQL Query could be suggested that would also be fine.

Comment: Can you show your input and output format in table structure?

Comment: i am new to SO, so i am able to see the results in table structure now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT rowno,mno,result from your_table
    order by rowno desc
```

Comment: you miss  `,` in your answer

Comment: The grouping gets disturbed with this query. Moreover there is no provision of selecting a particular mno value based on which you need to do the sorting of entire group

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ to DataSet (`dt` is your `DataTable`):

```
var sorted = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("rowno"))
               .CopyToDataTable();
```

Without LINQ:

```
var view = dt.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "rowno DESC";
var sorted = view.ToTable();
```

Comment: I just dont want to sort the entire datatable in descending order. What i want is : For a Particular mno value, say 82, the results are 20, 15, 30 corresponding to rowno 1,2,3. Then in the final outcome the result with rowno 2 should appear first, then with rowno 1 and last with rowno 3.I think i am more clear now. The entire grouping will remain like this just the entire groups will change their place.